# Fastcgi error with apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi

The guide i followed: http://www.howtoforge.com/using-php5-fpm-with-apache2-on-ubuntu-11.10-p2

The error I am getting:

```
    root@server:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
WARNING: MaxClients (10) must be at least as large
 as ThreadsPerChild (25). Automatically
 increasing MaxClients to 25.
Syntax error on line 45 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/mysite.net:
FastCgiExternalServer: redefinition of previously defined class "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi"
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
   ...fail!
```

The offending line 45:

```
FastCgiExternalServer /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi -socket /tmp/php5-fpm.sock -pass-header Authorization
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its likely that you've already defined `/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi` somewhere else.  **This can only be defined once**, and you probably want this in your `/etc/apache2/sites/default` directory as the instructions indicate.  You can see if you're defining it elsewhere by running:

```
grep -RIs "FastCgiExternalServer" /etc/apache2
```

Comment: so do i remove the offending line on other instances?